# Finding Funds by Sector Investment

Tags: mutual-funds

Until now my research on funds has been driven by the factsheets and details supplied by the investment platform that I use. It allows me to start from a fund and see where the investments are made to see if that is something I want to invest in.

Now I'd like to start driving the process more based on what/where I invest as a starting point rather than platform recommended or fund titles.

Unfortunately search terms like "Scottish renewables funds" tend to bring back articles about government investment or "0" results in a Funds platform search.

How do I go about finding funds invested in specific sectors or regions without using nebulous search terms like "Ethical" or "Green", which just hit on self applied fund names?

Comment: Try www.etfdb.com (though it might be US- or NA-only).

Answer (score 1):

One place to start would be at one of those sites that gives a score for each Fund. They may award points or stars based on how the fund performs in different conditions, or how much they charge in fees. Many funds mention the score they receive from these sites.

Because they rate many funds they should have a tool for searching by keywords. Unfortunately the best information at these sites are probably behind a paywall.

Comment: Can you give an example of any of these sites? I'm still too new to this to have that kind of ecosystem around me.